# Graphing two sets of data on one graph in VBA-excel

Tags: vba, excel, graph

I am using VBA for MS- excel 2010.  My assignment is to create a graph from a form that connects to an excel spreadsheet of data.  Basically the user selects two companies and my code behind the form will pull the data from the spreadsheet and graph the two sets of data from each company on the same graph.  The vertical axis will be the dates and the horizontal will be the monetary amount. My issue lies in trying to correctly graph the two sets on data on the same graph.  The sets of values and corresponding dates just aren't graphing right.  Here is what I've written (I am excluding code I deem irrelevant to the problem):

```vb
dates1 = "$E$2:$E$53"
startSym1 = "$I$2":$I$53" 
dates2 = "$E$522:$E$573"
startSym2 = "$I$522:$I$573"

ActiveSheet.Shapes.AddChart.Select
ActiveChart.ChartType = xlLine
ActiveChart.SetSourceData Source:=Range( _
"HistoryData!" & dates1 & ",HistoryData!" & startSym1 & ",HistoryData!" & dates2 & ",HistoryData!" & startSym2)
```

For some reason this only graphs one line? I would really appreciate some help one this thanks!
 Update:

```vb
ActiveSheet.Shapes.AddChart.Select
ActiveChart.HasTitle = True
ActiveChart.ChartTitle.Text = sym1 & " VS. " & sym2
ActiveChart.ChartType = xlLine
ActiveChart.SetSourceData Source:=Range( _
            "HistoryData!" & dates1 & ",HistoryData!" & startSym1)
Charts(sym1 & " VS. " & sym2).SeriesCollection.Add _
            Source:=Range("HistoryData!" & dates2 & ",HistoryData!" & startSym2)
```

From the suggested link, the site talked up separately adding each data set using the series collection property.  I am having syntax errors at the last line involving the Series collection property which makes me think I might have used it wrong.

Update: fixed the problem! Heres the solution

```vb
ActiveSheet.Shapes.AddChart.Select
ActiveChart.ChartType = xlLine
ActiveChart.HasTitle = True
ActiveChart.ChartTitle.Text = sym1 & " VS. " & sym2
ActiveChart.SetSourceData Source:=Range( _
            "HistoryData!" & dates1 & ",HistoryData!" & startSym1)
ActiveChart.SeriesCollection.Add _
            Source:=Worksheets("HistoryData").Range(startSym2)
```

Comment: You need to add a second series to the chart to graph a second line.  Each series can have only one source.  Check this [post](https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/4cf21336-47ea-46c7-9004-a3ca2c67e9b5/plot-multiple-series-in-one-graph-using-vba?forum=isvvba) out for a hint.

Comment: @Victoria if you have solved your issue, then pls post as an answer rather editing your question itself with solving part.

Comment: If you fixed your problem please answer your own question and accepted. A question is supposed to be just a question and a solution should be posted as an answer. Welcome to Stack Overflow @Victoria

Answer (score 0):

```
ActiveSheet.Shapes.AddChart.Select
ActiveChart.ChartType = xlLine
ActiveChart.HasTitle = True
ActiveChart.ChartTitle.Text = sym1 & " VS. " & sym2
ActiveChart.SetSourceData Source:=Range( _
        "HistoryData!" & dates1 & ",HistoryData!" & startSym1)
ActiveChart.SeriesCollection.Add _
        Source:=Worksheets("HistoryData").Range(startSym2)
```

Anwser